# match numbers in multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I have an HTML text like this

```
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Turnover</strong></td>
          <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;348,191</td>
              <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;856,723</td>
              <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;482,177</td>
          </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cost of sales</td>
          <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;275,708</td>
              <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;671,345</td>
              <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;357,587</td>
          </tr>
  <tr>
```

There's lots of html before and after it. I'd like to parse the numbers. There can be varying number of `td` columns, so I'd like to parse all of them. In this case, there are three columns, so the result I'm looking for is:

```
[348191, 856723, 482177]
```

Ideally, I'd like to parse the `Turnover` and `Cost of Sales` data separately into different variables

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crummy.com%2Fsoftware%2FBeautifulSoup%2F&ei=8f--UeiNGMm0iQfH1oG4CA&usg=AFQjCNHAxwplurFOBqg5cehWQEVKi-TuLQ&sig2=scm4SX8mAYtnHgiNZyGdng&bvm=bv.47883778,d.aGc):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """  <tr>
...     <td><strong>Turnover</strong></td>
...           <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;348,191</td>
...               <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;856,723</td>
...               <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;482,177</td>
...           </tr>
...   <tr>
...     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cost of sales</td>
...           <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;275,708</td>
...               <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;671,345</td>
...               <td width="20%" class="currency">&pound;357,587</td>
...           </tr>"""
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> for i in soup.find_all('tr'):
...     if i.find('td').text == "Turnover":
...             for x in i.find_all('td', {'class':'currency'}):
...                     print x.text
...
£348,191
£856,723
£482,177
```

### Explanation

First we convert the HTML to a `bs4` type which we can easily navigate through. `find_all`, no prizes for guessing what it does, finds all the `<tr>s`.

We loop through each tr and if the first `<td>` is Turnover, we then go through the rest of the `<td>s`.

We loop through each `td` with `class="currency"` and print its content.

Comment: Hi, that looks great. I've added another section to the example. What if I'm only interested in turnover?